# Leaftlet/shiny R map returning "ERROR: invalid 'type' (list) of argument" when combination chosen doesn't exist

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

Creating a leaflet map within a shiny app using R..

**The issue:**
I have 3 drops downs in my shiny app for my leaflet map (select Country, select Test Result, select Year).
The drop downs work fine. HOWEVER, When I input a combination from the drop downs, the map disappears and an error message pops up if the particular combination chosen doesn't exist.
(E.G. if i choose USA, negative, 1970; but USA didn't have any negative results in 1970, then map disappears and blank page with error message appears instead)

Error message says: "ERROR: invalid 'type' (list) of argument"

My question:
Is there a way to not return an error message and instead return something like a "combination not valid" message while maintaining the map on screen?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`validate`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html), which allows you to display an informative message:

```
validate(need(your_condition_for_validity,"Not valid combination"))
```